# Calculate the prime density for n-digit numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define

$$x=10^{n}$$

$$x_\text{max}=10^{n}-1$$

$$x_\text{min}=10^{n-1}$$

Using the [Prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) $\pi(x)$, the density is

$$\frac{\pi(x_\text{max}) - \pi(x_\text{min})}{9 x_\text{min}}$$

The [Prime-number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) says

$$\pi(x) \approx \frac{x}{\log(x)}$$

Substituting, the approx density is

$$\frac{\left(\frac{10^n - 1}{\log(10^n - 1)} - \frac{10^{n-1} - 1}{\log(10^{n-1} - 1)}\right)}{9 \cdot 10^{n-1}}$$

Rewriting in terms of $x_\text{min}$, we get

$$\frac{\left(\frac{10 x_\text{min}-1}{\log(10 x_\text{min}-1)} - \frac{x_\text{min}-1}{\log(x_\text{min}-1)}\right)}{9 x_\text{min}}$$

Is that a correct method to estimate the density of primes for all $n$-digit numbers?

Comment: I believe this is correct. In general if you want the density of primes in the interval $[a,b]$ (with $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$), you should just use $\frac{\pi(b)-\pi(a)}{b-a}$ which is what I believe you have done and then you just used the prime number theorem so it looks fine to me.

Comment: Agreed, looks good.

Comment: This is a valid approach as long as the interval in question is long enough. (If it's short, then the error term in the prime number theorem ≈ step becomes relevant.) One can simplify even further by using the mean value theorem in the numerator of your final fraction. The answer will be between $1/\log(10^{n-1})$ and $1/\log(10^n)$.

Comment: "One can simplify even further by using the mean value theorem in the numerator of your final fraction." Does that mean it's possible to further simplify this portion: $$\left(\frac{10 x-1}{\log(10 x-1)} - \frac{x-1}{\log(x-1)}\right)$$
Are there steps to show that? Thanks.